# Spring: error using Java Mapper from ibatis library. The interface is not a bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ibatis, mapper

I am developing a Back-end application using Java and Spring framework.
I start from an archetypal project which, however, causes some problems in the run phase.
I have this interface:

```
@Mapper
public interface MyInterface {

    public ReturnType1 method1(long myLong);

    @Select("SELECT * FROM myTab WHERE id = #{myLong}")
    public ReturnType2 method2(long myLong);

    ...
    ...
}
```

This interface uses the **ibatis** library (class `org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Mapper`);
Elsewhere in the code I have this service:

```
@Service
public class ExampleService {

    @Autowired
    private MyInterface myInterface;

    ...
}
```

where the `@Service` annotation is `org.springframework.stereotype.Service;`. Thanks to `@Autowired`, this service uses the interface that has `@Mapper` as an annotation (seen before).

However, in the run phase I get the following error:

**APPLICATION FAILED TO START**: Field `myInterface` required a bean of type `MyInterface` that could not be found. The injection point has the following annotations: `@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)`. Consider defining a bean of type '`MyInterface`' in your configuration.

Why is this error reported to me? I am not familiar with the **ibatis** library...  in my project I have an xml file in this path: **myProject/src/main/resources/mybatis/FileMapper.xml** and in the application.properties file I have this row:

```
mybatis.mapper-locations=classpath*:mybatis/*Mapper.xml
```

It seems to me that everything is configured correctly. Could you explain to me where and why I get this error?

Answer (score 0):

Hello add @MapperScan

```
@SpringBootApplication
@MapperScan("com.demo.mappers")
public class SpringbootDemoApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
```

}